# maria db galera cluster problem with docker container node

Tags: docker, mariadb, cluster-computing, replication, galera

I want to set up a MariaDB galera cluster with two nodes with different hosts having IP addresses 11.11.20.2 and 11.11.30.2. These two hosts can ping each other, and the databases have been launched via Docker-Compose and ports 4567 4444 4568 3306 with binding. The problem that has been bothering me for the past few days is that the container nodes cannot see each other, and I do not know how to set the values of the wsrep_node_address and wsrep_sst_receive_address variables for Docker to make the Docker node visible from the outside, and to prevent MariaDB from mistakenly going to the container's internal IP address. Can you please guide me on how to do this?

i want solution to make this issue ok and my mariadb docker containers see each other and the log of maria db dont tell me connection timed out again. thanks

Comment: can you show the compose file and the container logs.

Comment: I should have clarified, "by editing the question", there's really not enough comment space for it.

Comment: unfortunately yes and i must solve it quickly is there a way?

Comment: try using the container names rather than the IPs of them. The resolution is added to the `/etc/hosts` when the containers start and Galera will use this. Use less manual settings. Set BOOTSTRAP on only one node. "must solve it quickly" means you should have put more effort and details into the original question (and you still can edit it with details requested).

Comment: tnx for your help its ok now and solved with adding to /etc/hosts

now i have problem with iptables rules and idont know how to limit access to ports with iptables without having problem with docker rules